# Error: Incorrect time value: '2017-05-30 17:43:14 pm' for column 'time' at row 1

Tags: php, mysqli

this code is creating this error
"Error: Incorrect time value: '2017-05-30 17:43:14 pm' for column 'time' at row 1"
Please, someone, help me to fix this error

---

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
//check if form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']);
    //set date
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s a', time());

    //validation
    if(!isset($user) || $user=='' || !isset($message) || $message == ''){
        $error = "Please fill in your Name and Message";
        header("Location: index.php?error=" .urlencode($error));
            exit();

    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO shouts (user, message, time) VALUES('$user', '$message', '$time')";
        if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)){
            die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($con));
        }else{
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post your db schema and what the `time` column's type is.

Comment: is you field in database is of the type datetime? if not change it to datetime

Comment: @Exprator they can't use that, not with `2017-05-30 17:43:14 pm` using the `pm`. MySQL uses `YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00` - given if they want to keep using `$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s a', time());`.

Comment: `$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s a', time());` if your column is datetime, you need to get rid of `a', time()`.

Comment: I'm voting this question as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql 'DATE' column type accepts following date format 'Y-m-d'
'DATETIME' column accepts 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
furthermore '2017-05-30 17:43:14 pm' the PM part is not doing anything since 17:43:14 has all the information required.
Check your column type and adjust the input format accordingly.